# Linux cryptography strength outside USA?

Tags: linux, encryption, kernel, api, cryptography

Question:

The USA forbids the export of secure cryptography.
NSAKEY has already been discovered in the Windows cryptograhic API.

Since the Linux-Kernel is hosted in the USA, how secure is its cryptography ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USA doesn't forbid the export of secure cryptography. They used to, until 1996, when it became clear that it was pointless and the restrictions were dropped.